# In a Rails select menu, how can I make "00" appear instead of "0"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, select, formatting

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I want to apply rjust to the names in my select menu, so that people will select from “00” instead of “0” unless the number is two digits, in which case “10” would remain as “10”.  I have this

```
<%= select_tag(‘my_object[hour]', options_for_select((0..50).to_a), {:prompt => 'Select Hours’} ) %> hrs
```

but I can’t figure out how I apply the padding in there.  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
         (0..50).to_a.map { |i| i.to_s.rjust(2,'0')}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as following:

```
(0..50).map {|item| "%02d" % item}
```

I think it simple and easy to understand.

```
<%= select_tag(‘my_object[hour]', options_for_select((0..50).map {|item| "%02d" % item}), {:prompt => 'Select Hours’} ) %> hrs
```